# Bad notification for startForeground error when starting a service in android studio

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications, foreground-service

The error message is: android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification for startForeground

also dont know if its worth mentioning but the service starts normally on mac os.

My code:

```
public class App extends Application {

    public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "serviceChannel";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        createNotificationChannel();
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                    CHANNEL_ID,
                    "Service Channel",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            );

            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
        }
    }
```

- 

```
public class NotificationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification_service);

        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    }
    public void startService(View v) {
        String input = editText.getText().toString();
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationService.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("inputExtra", input);
        ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, serviceIntent);
    }
    public void stopService(View v) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationService.class);
        stopService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

**NotificationService**

```
public class NotificationService extends Service {


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        String input = intent.getStringExtra("inputExtra");
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                0, notificationIntent, 0);
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Reminder")
                .setContentText(input)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_android)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();
        startForeground(1, notification);
        //do heavy work on a background thread
        //stopSelf();
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you forgot to set the `NotificationChannel`. Add `.setChannelId(serviceChannel.getId())`

Comment: So i the issue is, i forgot to add the android name in the manifest: android:name=".notificationService.App" . How stupid of me. Thnk you tho

Answer (score 4):

So i the issue is, i forgot to add the android name in the manifest: android:name=".notificationService.App" . How stupid of me. Thnk you tho